# Не работают простые запросы типа SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Храню в MySQL словарь: 1 таблица, 2 столбца (`id` и `ru_word`).
Параметры второго столбца: тип `Varchar(100)`, сравнение `urf8_general_ci`.
Словарь добавлен в БД из файла следующим образом:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");

$handle = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {

    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {

        $word = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $buffer);
        $query = "INSERT INTO word_list VALUES (NULL, '$word')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($conn)); 
    }

    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Ошибка: fgets() неожиданно потерпел неудачу\n";
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

В phpMyAdmin делаю запрос `SELECT * FROM word_list WHERE ru_word = 'холодильник'` и запрос пуст (данное слово в словаре есть). Если же искать по `id`, то найдет.
Не пойму что не так, вроде все элементарно, а не робит.

Comment: Так столбец-то `word` или `ru_word`? Переносы строк проверяли?

Comment: @u_mulder, столбец ru_word. Дело не в неправильном названии. Переносы строк как проверить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что поле содержит только тот текст, который вы ищите (без лишних пробелов, переносов строк и прочего). Попробуйте запрос с `ru_word like '%холодильник%'` вместо `ru_word = 'холодильник'`. Проверьте [кодировку и сопоставление](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-charsets.html). Для MySQL тексты в таблице это просто последовательность бит, но создавая таблицу вы указываете (или используются значения по умолчанию), как эту последовательность интерпретировать в том числе в случае сопоставления.